# Give more priority for the first UILabel in a UIStackView when frame is smaller than required

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have an array of labels: `[UILabel]`, the count is according to the number of elements in an array. I'm adding them into a `UIStackView` by looping over them. At a point, the number of `UILabel`s exceeds the frame of the `UIStackView` in this situation I want the `UILabel`s that are added first to be shown and those added later to be hidden. What happens is the exact opposite. Like this:-

[image: screenshot]

I would like `text 1` preferred to be shown over `text 2` and so on. Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.alignment = .top
    stackView.axis = .vertical

    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.center = view.center
    stackView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 24)

    (0..<4).forEach {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "text \($0)"
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
}
```

FYI: I do not want to reverse the order.

Update: Thanks to @DonMag and @Rob I've set content compression resistance priority in my code. Unfortunately, I'm getting a different result for some reason from what @DonMag has depicted in his screenshots. Here's my updated code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    stackView.axis = .vertical

    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 150)

    (0..<15).forEach {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "text \($0)"
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
    var p: Float = 1000
    for v in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: p), for: .vertical)
        p -= 1
    }
}
```

And here's the result that I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Let me know if anyone has any trouble understanding the problem. This seems like it has a simple solution but, I can't figure it out in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You can specify a higher compression resistance priorities for the various labels.

Comment: @Rob I've tried `label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(Float($0)), for: .vertical)` and `label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(Float(4-$0)), for: .vertical)` both gives back the result where only the text 3 is getting visible.

Comment: I’d suggest 1000 (or `.required`) for label one and lower values for the others. But this is an imperfect solution. You might have to old-school on this and write your own class that calculates size of strings and employs your own custom hiding of subviews that can’t fit.

Comment: I tried `.required` for 1 and lower for rest, still gives the output where only 3 is shown. I don't really care if it's imperfect, I just want it to work. I would have made a custom class if this had been a big feature. Can't believe how complicated some things are in ios when compared with android, they have this working just as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    var p: Float = 1000
    for v in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: p), for: .vertical)
        p -= 1
    }
```

A bit of an odd way to use a stack view though, and it may not give you what you want after all.

For example, with a `100 x 150` frame, and 14 labels, we get:

[image]

as we see, the bottom label is a little "off."

And, with only 5 labels, we get:

[image]

The top label height gets stretched, unless we do the same thing with Content Hugging priority... in which case the bottom label would get stretched.

A better route would be to embed the stack view in a `UIView`, constrain Top / Leading / Trailing, set the height of the "container" `UIView`, and then make sure to set `.clipsToBounds = true` on the container view.

With 14 labels:

[image]

With 5 labels:

[image]

Here's the code to play with...

Method 1:

```
class FrankMethod1ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 150)
        
        // change to (0..<5) to see the stretching
        (0..<15).forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "text \($0)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }

        var p: Float = 1000
        for v in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: p), for: .vertical)
            p -= 1
        }

    }

}
```

Method 2:

```
class FrankMethod2ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let cView = UIView()
        cView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 150)
        cView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        // so we can see the view frame
        cView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        view.addSubview(cView)
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        
        cView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // change to (0..<5) to see NO stretching
        (0..<15).forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "text \($0)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

I don't think it's uncommon to see differences between Playground execution and Sim / Device.

Here's what I get:

[image]

when running this code in a Playground ... top two are "Method 1" with 15 & 5 labels, bottom two are "Method 2" with 15 & 5 labels:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class PlaygroundFrankViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stackView1 = UIStackView()
        stackView1.alignment = .leading
        stackView1.axis = .vertical
        
        view.addSubview(stackView1)
        stackView1.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 150)
        
        // change to (0..<5) to see the stretching
        (0..<15).forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "text \($0)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView1.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
        
        var p: Float = 1000
        for v in stackView1.arrangedSubviews {
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: p), for: .vertical)
            p -= 1
        }

        let stackView2 = UIStackView()
        stackView2.alignment = .leading
        stackView2.axis = .vertical
        
        view.addSubview(stackView2)
        stackView2.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 50, width: 100, height: 150)
        
        // change to (0..<5) to see the stretching
        (0..<5).forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "text \($0)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView2.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
        
        p = 1000
        for v in stackView2.arrangedSubviews {
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: p), for: .vertical)
            p -= 1
        }
        
        
        let cView1 = UIView()
        cView1.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 220, width: 100, height: 150)
        cView1.clipsToBounds = true
        
        // so we can see the view frame
        cView1.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        view.addSubview(cView1)
        
        let stackView3 = UIStackView()
        stackView3.alignment = .leading
        stackView3.axis = .vertical
        
        cView1.addSubview(stackView3)
        
        stackView3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView1.topAnchor),
            stackView3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView1.leadingAnchor),
            stackView3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView1.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // change to (0..<5) to see NO stretching
        (0..<15).forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "text \($0)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView3.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
        
        let cView2 = UIView()
        cView2.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 220, width: 100, height: 150)
        cView2.clipsToBounds = true
        
        // so we can see the view frame
        cView2.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        view.addSubview(cView2)
        
        let stackView4 = UIStackView()
        stackView4.alignment = .leading
        stackView4.axis = .vertical
        
        cView2.addSubview(stackView4)
        
        stackView4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView2.topAnchor),
            stackView4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView2.leadingAnchor),
            stackView4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView2.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // change to (0..<5) to see NO stretching
        (0..<5).forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "text \($0)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView4.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }

    }
    
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = PlaygroundFrankViewController()
```

Comment: How are you getting it right? What is wrong with my playground? I did the same code as you and getting different results. You're getting this on playgrounds, right? Or is it simulator? Shouldn't it work irrespective of that? Check out what I'm getting in the update with the exact same code.

Comment: @Frankenstein - distinctly different results between Playground and Simulator with "Method 1" ... matching output with Playground and Sim using "Method 2". As a side note, using Method 1 with simulator shows constraint issues when dropping into `Debug View Hierarchy` - which may explain the difference

Comment: The second method is pretty consistent. Also, should check out what's going on with method 1 in different situations. Thanks, DonMag.